# Microsoft Outlook add-in to automatically save generated report

Tags: c#, beginner, outlook

This is my first C# project, so feel free to be brutal.  :)

I have an automated external process on another machine generate and email a budget report to me every Sunday.  This program is a Microsoft Outlook add-in that automatically fetches those emails and saves the attached report to a particular location on my hard drive organized by year.  Here's the algorithm:

1. if there is no unread email in the mail folder, quit
2. otherwise, save the attachment to a subfolder under the year
3. renaming it to append the date

Because it's tied to the new email event, it only runs once each time new a new email is received.

This is the code which includes some autogenerated code.

### BudgetTool.cs

```
using System;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace BudgetToolAddIn
{
    public partial class BudgetTool
    {
        private void BudgetTool_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
                .ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(ThisApplication_NewMail);
        }

        private void ThisApplication_NewMail()
        {
            string folderName = "Budget Reports";
            // the destiationFolder must include the trailing \
            string destinationFolder = @"C:\users\Edward\planning\budget\";
            Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = Application.ActiveExplorer()
                    .Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Parent;
            try
            {
                inBox = inBox.Folders[folderName];
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(@"Can't find folder '" + folderName + "'");
                return;
            }
            Outlook.Items inBoxItems = inBox.Items;
            Outlook.MailItem newEmail = null;
            inBoxItems = inBoxItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true");
            try
            {
                foreach (object collectionItem in inBoxItems)
                {
                    newEmail = collectionItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                    if (newEmail != null)
                    {
                        if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                        {
                            for (int i = 1; i <= newEmail
                               .Attachments.Count; i++)
                            {
                                const string extension = ".csv";
                                string originalFileName = newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName;
                                if (originalFileName.EndsWith(extension))
                                {
                                    int extloc = originalFileName.LastIndexOf(extension);
                                    DateTime date = newEmail.SentOn;
                                    string year = date.ToString("yyyy");
                                    string fileName = originalFileName.Remove(extloc, extension.Length) + "_" + date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + extension;
                                    newEmail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(destinationFolder + year + @"\" + fileName);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorInfo = (string)ex.Message
                    .Substring(0, 11);
                if (errorInfo == "Cannot save")
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(@"Create Folder <{destionationFolder}>");
                }
            }
        }


        private void BudgetTool_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Note: Outlook no longer raises this event. If you have code that 
            //    must run when Outlook shuts down, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(BudgetTool_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(BudgetTool_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: __WHY U NO USING VBA__ ;-)

Comment: @Phrancis:  OK, **that** was brutal.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it seems to be a "for-your-own-eyes-only"-function I will not comment on the hard coded paths and other strings :-).

This syntax

> ```
>         this.Application.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(ThisApplication_NewMail);
> ```

has a short form:

```
this.Application.NewMail += ThisApplication_NewMail;
```

---

In

> ```
> if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
> {
>   for (int i = 1; i <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i++)
>   {
>     ...
> ```

the `if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)`-check is unnecessary.

---

This catch statement is somewhat incomplete:

> ```
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             string errorInfo = (string)ex.Message
>                 .Substring(0, 11);
>             if (errorInfo == "Cannot save")
>             {
>                 System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(@"Create Folder <{destionationFolder}>");
>             }
>         }
> ```

You are only handling one special Exception. What about notifying if anything else going wrong? Why not handle the special Exception for missing folder in a dedicated exception handler?

If the Exception for missing folder is not a sub class of `Exception` then you could experiment with something like:

```
  }
  catch (Exception ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("Cannot save"))
  {
    ...
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ...
  }
```

Or maybe it's a better approach to check for the existence of the destination folder before the loop, and if missing exit more "gracefully" (or maybe just create it if the application has the rights to do that)?

---

You are exposing errors in modal message boxes. What will happen if a message box halts the event progress and a new email arrives?

Comment: I don't usually write for Windows.  What's a better way of handling errors that doesn't use modal message boxes?

Comment: @Edward: The canonical way is to log to the Windows event log - in .net through the System.Diagnostics.EvnetLog api https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzwc042w(v=vs.110).aspx. Or you could just write to a simple text file.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the EventLog even to my worst enemy ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> newEmail = collectionItem as Outlook.MailItem;
> if (newEmail != null)
> {
> }
> ```

You can replace this with a nice filter-expression like:

```
if (collectionItem is Outlook.MailItem newEmail)
{
    ...
}
```

This way the additional variable declaration

> ```
> Outlook.MailItem newEmail = null;
> ```

is no longer necessary.

---

> ```
> originalFileName.EndsWith(extension)
> ```

Windows paths are case-insensitive so comparing extensions is better done with

```
originalFileName.EndsWith(extension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

---

> ```
> originalFileName.Remove(extloc, extension.Length)
> ```

You don't have to extract file names and extensions manually. There is a simpler API for handling this. It's *hidden* in the static `Path` class:

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(..)
```

and

```
Path.GetExtension(..)
```

Comment: I suspected there was a better way to handle file paths and extensions, and even searched, but the API is huge and I couldn't find it.  Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, I wish I could mark both answers as "accepted."

Comment: @Edward thanks ;-) I know what you mean, I often feel the same.